# HTTP Redirect on a browser without showing intermediate window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, redirect, iis

I have two servers someserver.com and anotherserver.com

What I need is when a user clicks on someserver.com he or she will be redirected to anotherserver.com

Currently when I do a redirect programatically on the server (ASP.NET MVC IIS)
what a user see is: 1) someserver.com is loaded 2)anotherserver.com is loaded.

What i want is when a user clicks on someserver.com he sees only anotherserver.com in his browser.

Does http protocol allow it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of approaches to this but the simplest one of you own the domain is to just use domain forwarding st the dns level. Then it won't involve your web server at all. Otherwise, the browser will always have to load the first site, if only briefly, before loading the second one. You can optimize this by just sending a redirect, which should be barely noticeable. Another option would be client-side JavaScript, but if you know on the client that you want to go to the new URL, you could just use a standard hyperlink to it at that point (so I assume this is not an option).